# Error Messages When Booting Up

Tags: 14.04

These signs show up when booting Ubuntu 14.04. Just right before Ubuntu logo shows up.

Here's the error prompts:

[image]

What do these mean?

Comment: Do you have two hard drives on your computer? Or did you boot it with SD card / USB stick connected?

Comment: Hi @P.-H.Lin! I only have one drive with multiple partitions. I boot it from my local drive. I have an SD card always connected to my PC though, I use it as a ReadyBoost when I'm on Windows? Is it related to this error prompt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing your SD, as these errors are talking about your second drive. If you only have one built in hdd, it probably is your SD-card Ubuntu can not properly access. I would think it might be formatted in a strange file system or has physical errors.